# report a variable from all patches in behavior space netlogo

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I have a model in NetLogo that simulates insects(turtles) herbivory on plants (patches). Each patch has a variable called resources that is depleted every time a turtle visits it. I would like to report the resources of each patch and the patch coordinates when running my model through behavior space.

So far I have:

```
to-report damageToPatches
  foreach sort patches [ ask patches [
    report resources ]]
end
```

Which obviously doesn't work, this might be pretty simple but I am struggling to come up with a solution. Might it involve adding the resource value of each patch to list at every time step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I just make the smallest modification to your code to make it operational, we get:

```
to-report damage-to-patches
  report [resources] of patches
end
```

But you said you want to include the patch coordinates too, so that'd be:

```
to-report damage-to-patches
  report [(list pxcor pycor resources)] of patches
end
```

`of` gives results in random order, though. If you want the list in left-to-right, top-to-bottom order, then that's:

```
to-report damage-to-patches
  report map [[(list pxcor pycor resources)] of ?] sort patches
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a huge help!

Comment: sorry, pretty new to this